# Does falling ever cause damage?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've noticed that I can fall a fair distance without taking damage, but I've never fallen any farther than I could survive.  If you fall far enough is it possible to take damage, or is falling damage just not accounted for?  Are there kill zones if you fall off the map or into unreachable areas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, falling never causes damage.  However, there *are* places that result in insta-death if you fall there.

One good way to tell a fall will result in death is to pay attention to the map.  If your destination falls outside the boundaries of the map, odds are you wont survive the journey.

Comment: I would just add that falling _in a vehicle_ causes damage _to the vehicle_. It seems odd to me that, physics-wise, vehicles are damaged when falling a few feet into a ditch but people can jump a hundred feet off of a building and not lose even a single point of health. One would think that the same amount of force it takes to break a fender would easily be enough to break a leg.

Comment: Vehicles don't take damage from falling or crashing, only from being shot.